# What does "有蛋黄的迎春花" mean?

Tags: translation

走进公园，我们感到春天真的来了。柳条迎着暖风轻轻地摆动，绿茵茵的草坪相扑了柔软的地毯。花都开了，**有蛋黄的迎春花**，粉红的桃花，白色的玉兰花，还有紫色的丁香花。

I'm reading this story above about these students going into a park. The part in bold I don't understand- as far as I know, it means "there were egg yolk winter jasmine flowers", but I'm sure that's not right.

Comment: Though not ungrammatical, that's an uncommonly-used ways to express golden, if it's not a typo for 淡黄. For golden, instead of 蛋黄, usally we say 金黄.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[迎春](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BF%8E%E6%98%A5%E8%8A%B1)（学名：Jasminum nudiflorum），又称金腰带，香港俗称串串金，是木犀科素馨属的植物。早春先于叶子开放出黄色鲜艳的小花(bright yellow flowers)，给人们带来春意，所以花名曰迎春。

[Winter jasmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasminum_nudiflorum) (Jasminum nudiflorum) is a slender, deciduous shrub native to China. It is widely cultivated as an ornamental and is reportedly naturalized in France and in scattered locations in the United States.

[image]

Let's inspect the structure of the phrases.

蛋黄的迎春花
粉红的桃花
白色的玉兰花
紫色的丁香花

These are appositives.
They have the same pattern, color + flower name.

The author uses two words (+ 的) to describe a color.
Thus, 蛋黄色 is simplified to 蛋黄, and 粉红色 to 粉红.

蛋黄(色)的花 egg yellow flowers

Answer (score 1):

[image: 淡黄]
原文这里是出现了错别字,所以产生了歧义.所以原文这里 表示的只是淡黄色的花,与蛋没有关系.

Answer (score 0):

蛋黄的 is 蛋黄色的 means color like egg yolk